# How do nested Javascript returns "pass up" promises?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

This question has two parts, both relating to how Javascript promises are passed around functions using return statements.

***1)***

I have simple Javascript function, which includes multiple return statements. The inner function returns a promise to an arrow function, the arrow function is also returned, like this:

```
const returnMe(data){
  return () => {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  };
};
```

Could I write the following code?

```
returnMe("Hello!").then((msg) => { console.log(msg) }); /// --> output "Hello!" ??
```

**In other words, if a nested function receives a resolved/rejected promise, and that function is returned to it's parent function, does the parent function receive the resolved/rejected promise?**

***2)***

Another, related but somewhat different example....

```
 const returnMe(data){
    return () => {
      return Promise.resolve(data).then(() => { console.log("Ha!") });
    };
 };
```

In this case, the "then" call happens inside the function. **Does the then call "use up" the promise? In this case, what is returned to the arrow function, and then to the parent function?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) `returnMe("Hello!").then` will give you an error, because the function returned by `returnMe` is a function, and has no `.then` method ... 2) calling `returnMe` will result in a function ... the function needs to be executed

Comment: *Could I write the following code?* I'm a bit curious why you don't just run it and see for yourself?

Comment: Fair question –– I wanted to understand the logic behind why it was behaving the way it was. Obviously I ran these snippets but didn't really understand why they weren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since `returnMe()` returns a function, you have to call that function. That will return a promise, which you can then use with `.then()`

```js
function returnMe(data){
  return () => {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  };
};

returnMe("Hello!")().then(msg => console.log(msg));
```

2) The inner `.then()` consumes the data that the promise resolves to, but it returns a new promise. So you can call `.then()` on this.

As with example 1, you need to call the function that `returnMe()` returns in order to execute the inner function.

```js
function returnMe(data){
    return () => {
      return Promise.resolve(data).then(() => { console.log("Ha!") });
    };
 };
 
 returnMe("Hello!")().then(() => console.log("Done!"));
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand why this wasn't working as I expected.